# Is there a replacement for "contain: content" for safari?

Tags: html, css, sass, safari

I am trying to find a replacement for the css property **"contain: content"** for Safari (since it works perfectly on Chrome), but I can't find any. Is there some kind of other css property that creates a similar effect?

Comment: No, Safari don't know it (and there is no prefixed/unprefixed equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

As of 2022/3/15, Safari 15.4 was released with built-in `content` CSS property support.

Please read the [Safari 15.4 release note here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safari-release-notes/safari-15_4-release-notes).